What do you lubricate a Fernco hub donut with?
I'm using a Fernco donut which is rubber ring to replace a vertical iron pipe with a PVC pipe while retaining the old iron p-trap. I am retaining the old p-trap because I'm like 20 inches into a footer, and I'm tired of jack hammering -- Ideally I would love to replace that too. This is for a shower. What should I lubricate the Fernco donut with when I insert into into the iron hub? Different people use,

grease?
pvc glue?
or silicone?
Or should I just install them dry and bang them in with a hammer? And also this guy


The official installation guide  (available online but not provided with the product) calls for lubricating ONLY the outside of the ring, and with a "soap solution".


Straight up dish soap is best and least messy. If you have the option, install the side in contact with the old pipe first. It's usually much rougher. Slide over the new pipe.

A...personal lubricant...would probably also suit.

Fernco's are elastomeric PVC, they are basically chemically resistant to everything.... that you would likely choose to be a lube for it.  For starters look up a chemical compatibility chart for PVC.
Any typical oil... air tool oil, gun oil, greases; depends on what's most convenient and then also compatible with the pipe material as well as not adversely affecting the ability of the fernco to slip and not seal.
megalock dope which is watery and blueish in color, compared to the thick traditional PTFE types of dope, tends to work nice and is a nice balance between lube and sealant, and easily cleans up with a wet rag.

Good information, however knowing the instructions calls for soapy solution, I think I would just use that. But this does explain why everyone on the internet has a different idea on how to lubricate this donuts. This was the reason for the question anyway. One dude even using PVC glue to lubricate it.

cashier glances at my personal lubricant on conveyor belt and grins... no no no it's for my fernco coupling

instructions are often subjective, and definitely written from the manufacturer's perspective of risk and liability

so you either know what you are doing, or just follow the science and keep jack hammering
